# Create Sub-DataTable using LINQ, and return a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

I've created a `void method` aiming at deriving a `sub - DataTable` using `LINQ` query, and I wonder after several failures on the best way to retrieve the sub-table by keeping the `DataTable` type. My main matter comes from the `implicitly typed` variable `sublookup` that retrieves an object of type `IEnumerable<T>`. So far any attempt to convert `IEnumerable<T>` back to `DataTable` has been failing.

```
public void subtbl()
    {
        string LookUpFile;
        DataTable LookUpTable = new DataTable();
        string[] LookUpDir = RetrieveFileDirectory();

        for (int i = 0; i < LookUpDir.Length; i++)
        {
            LookUpFile =LookUpDir[i];
            if (LookUpFile.Contains("Brand"))
            {
                LookUpTable = ConvertTextFileToDataTable(LookUpFile);

                 var sublookup = LookUpTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new { col1 = x["Mac"], col2 = x["Win"],
                    col3 = x["zo"], col4 = x["dz"], col5 = x["dx"],
                    col6 = x["zx"] });

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n ... stuck");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }

    }
```

As a way around, I could have used lots of `DataTable.Columns.Remove("columnname")`, but I concede this approach is not very `efficient` in particular if the Parent `DataTable` contains lots of `columns`.

**EDIT:** Sticking to a solution using *LINQ*

```
   var dataRow = LookUpTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new { col1 = x.Field<string>("Mac"),
                                       col2 = x.Field<string>("Win"),
                                       col3 = x.Field<string>("zo"), 
                                       col4 = x.Field<string>("dz"), 
                                       col5 = x.Field<string>("dx"),
                                       col6 = x.Field<string>("zx") })

   DataTable look = dataRow.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

I end up with *Error:* `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>` does not contain a definition for `CopyToDataTable`...., despite the add of `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` in `References` and knowing that `CopyToDataTable()` method is used to convert the `IEnumerable<DataRow>` back to the `DataTable`.

Best,

Comment: You have to fill your `DataTable`, for example in a loop. But i must admit that i don't understand your requirement. Are those properties in the anonymous type that you select the columns that you want to have in the new `DataTable`? So this table has a different schema than the original table?

Comment: `DataTable` is filled already with `LookUpTable` and the `sub-table` is a filtered version of the original table (_caeteris paribus_)

Comment: To make it clear, the main idea was to declare  `public DataTabe subtbl()` and return `sublookup`, but given the failure to keep the `sub-table` as `DataTable` using `Linq`, i switch back to `void`

Answer (score 0):

I would use following approach, no LINQ needed and recommended:

```
var allSubTables = new List<DataTable>();
string[] relevantColumns = { "Mac", "Win", "zo", "dz", "dx", "zx", };
DataTable lookUpTable = new DataTable();
foreach (string colName in relevantColumns)
    lookUpTable.Columns.Add(colName);

foreach (string t in LookUpDir)
{
    LookUpFile = t;
    if (LookUpFile.Contains("Brand"))
    {
        DataTable textFileTable = ConvertTextFileToDataTable(LookUpFile);
        DataTable subTable = lookUpTable.Clone(); // same columns, empty
        foreach (DataRow row in textFileTable.Rows)
        {
            DataRow addedRow = subTable.Rows.Add(); // already added now
            foreach (DataColumn col in subTable.Columns)
                addedRow.SetField(col.ColumnName, row.Field<string>(col.ColumnName));
        }
        allSubTables.Add(subTable);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n ... stuck");
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Tim`: Thanks for the willingness to support, although i still look for a `linq` solution as indicated in the edited post.

Comment: @dark.vador: Why? Never use LINQ to modify something but to query something. DataTables are special types which you should not fill with LINQ. One reason is that every row or column stores it's table as a reference and everytime you try to add this to another table you will get an exception.
Every LINQ solution would be less efficient and less safe than the one i've provided (f.e. using a `CopyToDataTable<Anything>`). Another drawback of `CopyToDataTable`: you'll get an exception if the input sequence was empty. So you need two queries.

Comment: However, if you insist on it, here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ok. thx. fyi : `string[] LookUpDir = RetrieveFileDirectory()`